# Python class with a label inside of frame

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make my own tkinter widgets.

Right now I am working on custom radiobuttons. The idea is to have each radiobutton to actually be a frame, inside of which is a canvas that is next to a label.

The canvas is the circle that fills when clicked upon, and the label displays the text that indicates what the radiobutton controlls.

I have created a class for such widgets that looks like this..

```
class Custom_RadioButton(Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        Frame.__init__(self, *args)
```

I am having trouble figuring out how to add the label and canvas inside of this frame because it does not really have a name to place anywhere like `Label.__init__(self, Framename, *args)`

Thanks

Comment: The contents would just be `Canvas(self, ...)` and `Label(self, ...)` - there is no reason to use anything like `Label.__init__(...)` except inside a custom widget that derives from `Label`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
import tkinter as tk   # <-- avoid star imports

class Custom_RadioButton(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs)
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self)               # place a canvas into self (a Frame)
        self.canvas.pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)

        self.label = tk.Label(self.canvas, text='clickme')  # place a label in self.canvas
        self.canvas.create_oval(.....)   # draw a circle on self.canvas
```

Comment: what exactly does `super()` do? Is that a tkinter widget?

Comment: super calls the parent class, here tk.Frame, but does not hardcode it. See this video to understand how it works in details: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EiOglTERPEo